# How to navigate a webpage contaning multiple html sources?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

I am working on a webpage crawler and find that my target webpage whose url is like

```
http::/www.xxxxx.com/main.aspx?View=xxxxBrandName=xxxxIsSsoLogin=xxx
```

And when I try to look at the source of this webpage, I find that there are many different
html sources if I right click on different positions and the result is also different if I click `View->Source` in `IE` (I can only use IE to open this website).

I am very new to HTML so I can't tell what happened exactly. Any one can give me any clue on this?

Answer (score 0):

On chrome right click + inspect element and go to the sources tab, there you can browse through all the sources. Furthermore on Firefox you can use firebug to do similar things.

It's hard to say what exactly is causing the different results when you view source but it is possible that the page just has a lot of random crap e.g. add-ons, plugins etc.

Comment: It's a pity that I can only use IE to access the website. Could you please provide me some methods under IE? Thanks!

Comment: You can use f12 tools in IE 8 to inspect element.

Comment: @BhoomtawathPlinsut I have tried, but didn't figured out how to locate the source of one specific module.

Comment: @Chitanda To inspect an element, there is  a button of a pointer. Click it and click on any element of your choice.

Comment: @Chitanda To inspect an element, there is a button of a pointer. Click it and click on any element of your choice. If the displayed source isn't updated, find a button to that looked like a refresh button(should be the 4th) to clear some caches and inspect element again.